# Changing 'date' column in mysql workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql

I am currently exploring a CSV dataset with 6 different tables on MYSql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7PeA.jpg)

I am unable to Format the date column in mm-dd-yyyy format. I tried using convert() & CAST() function but still does not workout

Can anyone guide me?

```sql
SELECT 
date,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), date, 103) AS "new_date",
FROM production_sales_forecast; 

SELECT CAST(date as DATE)
FROM 
production_sales_forecast;
```

I just want the entire column to be formatted in dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: In your first attempt, you appear to be trying to use T-SQL's `CONVERT` function. SQL Server <> MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to convert a string to date and [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to format the date value according to the format string.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("3/1/2020", "%e/%m/%Y");
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("3/1/2020", "%e/%m/%Y"),"%m-%d-%Y") as my_new_date ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c5458870cf673f83513226bc90ce70e5